# Select a string between two characters in a loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server column which contains values like

```
    [157;#10 - S1 Pawl Cap],
    [168;#11 - S2 Two],
    [180;#11 - S2 TwoB],
    [153;#11-H3 Snowboard],
    [173;#12 - Fishing (CA Surf Casting)],
    [155;#12 - Fishing (Colorado)],
    [162;#12 - H3 Snow],
    [164;#12 - Internal Mono/Silver L5],
    [158;#12 - L5 Bike],
    [163;#12 - L5 Casual],
    [156;#12 - L5 Kids],
    [174;#12 - Nordic],
    [159;#12 - S2 Snap In Bike],
    [160;#12 - S2 Snap In Casual],
    [161;#12 - Treksta EX735],
    [185;#13 - 2nd Taste of Boa - External Test],
    [170;#13 - Fishing],
    [176;#13 - Gaerne Moto],
    [188;#13 - IP1 - FT 1 Bike and Run],
    [177;#13 - IP1 - FT 2 Bike],
    [178;#13 - IP1 - FT 2 Running],
    [154;#13 - Mono Stage 1 - Filament 2 Running],
    [175;#13 - Mono Stage 2 - Filament 3 Casual],
    [169;#13 - Mono Stage 2 - Filament 3 Running],
    [184;#13 - Retrofit Day - 4/5/13 Internal Test],
    [165;#13 - Vasque Open Race],
    [191;#13 - Winter HP88],
    [181;#13 - Winter NER],
    [192;#13 - Winter Webbing],
    [190;#13 - Zonal 1],
    [205;#14 - Cassowary],
    [207;#14 - DC Motocross Project],
    [204;#14 - Fishing (HP88SW)],
    [197;#14 - Golden Eagle],
    [198;#14 - Golf Pants Catching],
    [179;#14 - GOLF Test],
    [200;#14 - IP1 Agro Road Bike],
    [202;#14 - IP1 FT3],
    [182;#14 - L6 FT1],
    [193;#14 - L6 FT2],
    [183;#14 - Landscaping (Utility)],
    [195;#14 - No Sew Guides],
    [210;#14 - PC Replacement],
    [167;#14 - Running Suite FT ZERO],
    [166;#14 - Specialized Suite],
    [201;#14 - Track Spike],
    [203;#14 - Winter Snow],
    [216;#15 - American Football],
    [213;#15 - Boa Kids],
    [196;#15 - Cassowary],
    [212;#15 - Golf (IP1 Heel)],
    [215;#15 - L5 Running No Sew],
    [211;#15 - L6 No Sew],
    [208;#15 - L6 T1 Shots],
    [209;#15 - Mountaineering EMEA],
    [186;#15 - Redwing Utility Test],
    [187;#15 - Run Suite FT2],
    [206;#15 - Running NC722 Color],
    [217;#15 - S2-S No-Sew],
    [219;#15 - Snowboard],
    [221;#16 - Fit Lab],
    [225;#16 - Golf TX],
    [222;#16 - Internal FormTX],
    [228;#16 - OBG Snow],
    [227;#16 - OG Running],
    [194;#16 - OG Trail],
    [224;#16 - PVDF Lace],
    [214;#16 - Run Suite FT2 Two],
    [171;#16 - S3 Bike],
    [223;#16 - Summer Snow],
    [218;#16 - Trudel Fit Test],
    [226;#16 - TX5 Utility],
    [220;#16 - Unbranded Running],
    [189;#16 - Winter Snow],
    [199;#17 - M4],
    [172;#17 - S3 FT2]
```

I would like to select all the repeated values between `[` and `;`.

From the above I would like to select 157,168 and so on.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by repeated values? The values 157 and 168 both only appear once in your sample data. If you can explain what you expect as output we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I modified a split/parse function for such items.  Rather than passing one delimiter, we pass two (a begin and an end).  These delimiters can be any non-like strings.  For example `<div>` and `</div>`  or in your case  **[** and **;**.

**Example**

```
-- Original String Truncated for Demo
Declare @String varchar(max) = '[157;#10 - S1 Pawl Cap],[168;#11 - S2 Two],[180;#11 - S2 TwoB],[153;#11-H3 Snowboard]'

Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](@String,'[',';')
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1)
 From (Select A.N,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L))) From cte4 A ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - If a Comma Delimited String is Desired**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,YourCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'[157;#10 - S1 Pawl Cap],[168;#11 - S2 Two],[180;#11 - S2 TwoB],[153;#11-H3 Snowboard]')

Select A.ID
      ,B.String
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select String = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +RetVal 
                 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](YourCol,'[',';')
                 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
             ) B
```

Returns

```
ID  String
1   153,157,168,180,...  --<< Original String was truncated for demo
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your answer/solution.

Comment: @user6731714 Happy it helped.

Comment: @user6731714 I know you can't vote just yet, but you can ACCEPT the answer if you desire

Comment: I would like to.But I do not see that option.Sorry about that

Comment: @user6731714 If this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346416). This will show your appreciation for the people who spent their own time to help you.